# Function not in prolog

Tags: prolog

sibling(X, Y):- father(Z, X), father(Z, Y), not (X=Y).

sister(X, Y):- father(Z, X), father(Z, Y), female(X).

brother(X, Y):- father(Z, X), father(Z, Y), male(X).

[image]

i'm having a bit problem with using the not function. i've tried not X=Y. but to no avail, the sibling rule still produce error.

if i were to delete the not x=y, the output will be a bit kind of "ugly".
how should i write the not function?

Comment: You could write X\=Y or even better use iso predicate dif/2 and write : dif(X,Y).

Comment: thank you very much sir. I got the correct output. :)

Answer (score 1):

The **ISO predicate** implementing *not provable* is called `(\+)/1`.

However, as @coder explains in the comments, it is **much better** to use `dif/2` to express that two terms are **different**.

`dif/2` is a **pure** predicate that works correctly in all directions, also if its arguments are not yet instantiated.

For example, with `(\+)/1`, we get:

```
?- \+ (X = Y ).
false.
```

No `X` and `Y` exist that satisfy this goal, right? **Wrong**:

```
?- X = a, Y = b, \+ (X = Y ).
X = a,
Y = b.
```

In contrast, with `dif/2`:

```
?- dif(X, Y).
dif(X, Y).
```

and **in particular**:

```
?- X = a, Y = b, dif(X, Y).
X = a,
Y = b.
```

See [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) for more information. `dif/2` is with us since the very first Prolog system. I strongly recommend you use it.

Answer (score 0):

**SWI Prolog** has no `not`operator. it can be used as a regular compound term, e.i. `not(X)`.

It must be no space between *functor* and *open parenthesis*:

**foo(** argument list ).

This is the cause of the error.

[**SWI Prolog** suggests ISO-standard replacement for `not/1`: `(\+)/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%2B/1)